# Splash Screen with busy Indicator in worklight app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on a new app where it is needed to add a busy indicator or progressive bar in the splash screen . It is a hybrid app . So the implementation should in Web resources(html, js and css) and the app is done in worklight so the implementation should also be in worklight . Do you have any suggestion to solve this issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Hybrid applications the ability to control over the splash screen (= change its appearance, duration, and other things like that), is currently not possible in the manner you would like - by using HTML, JS, CSS...

The ability to do so (in *Android* and *iOS* only) will be introduced in Worklight 6.2, to be released in June 2014 (this month), where you could decide how and what to display. For example: An animation or a rotating set of images, etc.

Comment: Any suggestion what i can do in the above requirement

Comment: Yes. Upgrade to 6.2 once released.

Comment: Is there a way to do some thing like showing couple of images for splash screen in worklight so that it looks like animation .

Comment: Sure, but this will have to happen AFTER the splash screen provided by Worklight was already removed, meaning the app has already finished loading... after that you can display any image you'd like via JS, but what you will actually do is make your users wait more time to get to the app, and that's bad user experience.

Comment: I want to have the splash screen like with please wait and busy indicator . What can i do. I also wanted to ask, Is there any way to implement transparent tutorial in hybrid app common to all environment.

Comment: You can't do this image in 6.1 and below as far as I know in Web code.

Comment: As for a tutorial of how to use the app - that's not related to Worklight at all. That's just pure JS that you will need to run in your app when it is launched for the first time (a simple boolean...); There is no example provided for that (as it is not related to Worklight, it's just pure JS code).

Comment: Can you tell me how to setup some alert that happens only once when the app is opened for the first time in worklight

Comment: Create a global var firstLaunch = false; then, in wlCommonInit() check if it is false - set it to true and display an alert. else, do nothing because it's already true so you don't want to display the alert...