# Splash Screen with loading in four environment(android,ios,blackberry and windows) using html coding or common plugin for hybrid apps

Tags: javascript, html, css, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I want a splash screen with a loading indicator or busy indicator or progress bar in all major environment(android,ios,blackberry and windows) in html,css and javascript or common plugin which can added in my web resource code and the output will be seen in all the environment. How can i implement this. Any useful resource or common plugin to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit June 6th:*

What you can try to do, in Android, is:

1. Delete the drawable\splash.9.png image
2. In src\com... yourApp.java add after the `onCreate`

   ```
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   this.setStringProperty("LoadingDialog", "mytext1");
   ```

This will display some dialog with the text "mytext1".
The dialog will be dismissed once the app finished loading.

From here on you can add your own native code to display an image with some indicator on top of it - maybe. you'll need to implement that and see if it works, but this is the location to do it.

This is all native, not web. You can't do this in web code.

And similarly in iOS.
Don't know about BB and WP8.

---

Balaji,
The answer to this question will not be any different from your exact already-answered question: [Splash Screen with busy Indicator in worklight app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028556/splash-screen-with-busy-indicator-in-worklight-app). This is a duplicate question.

Prior to Worklight 6.2 (to be released this month, June 2014), you *cannot* create a custom splash screen behavior as the one you've described. Asking this again is not going to change the answer. :-)

This is not doable using *web* code, because the splash screen is invoked from *native* code while the framework and application are being initialized. To alter the behavior of the splash screen you need to write native code, to produce a different experience.

As said, this will be possible in Worklight 6.2, for Android and iOS (= will *not* be possible for Windows Phone and BlackBerry at this time).

As an illustration, you could do something that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you give me reference from where you have implemented the above screen shot

Comment: This was an illustration of what you could do in Worklight 6.2, to be released later this month.

Comment: Where is the splash screen implementation in worklight in current version. There should some java file where the splash screen implementation will be . Where it is.

Comment: Where is the splash screen implementation in worklight 6.1 in android.