# Splash screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, ibm-mobilefirst

I am having a application which have a splash screen. My problem is i need a splash screen with the pinwheel spinner(progress bar). I have also added the android java code.

Java code

```
package com.SSF;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.worklight.androidgap.WLDroidGap;

public class SSF extends WLDroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    /**
     * onWLInitCompleted is called when the Worklight runtime framework initialization is complete
     */
    @Override
    public void onWLInitCompleted(Bundle savedInstanceState){


        super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath());

        // Add custom initialization code after this line
    }

}
```

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on internet which explain how to do a splash screen (and where you have to replace the text proposed by a progress bar). Start by this, and then come back later if you have some issue.

Comment: Why did you change the entire question to handle IOS ? all of the answers are already for android... you should create a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Having a splash screen is redundant, and should be avoided unless maybe it's the first run of the app. Users like to open the app and start using it right away.

Only really heavy apps (mostly games ) need to load a lot of things, but even there, there are plenty of optimizations to make it short (just load what it needs in the near future, for example).

Anyway, for the progress bar, just create a layout with a progress bar view in the middle, use "setContentView" on it, and that's it...

You can also customize the progress bar by yourself, for example using [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915561/how-does-progressbar-drawable-work).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. please

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView splashImageView;
    boolean splashloading = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        splashImageView = new ImageView(this);
        splashImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        splashImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        setContentView(splashImageView);
        // interesting music
        /**
         * Gets your sound file from res/raw
         */
        splashloading = true;
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                splashloading = false;
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }

        }, 3000);

    }
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Where is the progress bar i asked for?

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
// METHOD 1     

         /****** Create Thread that will sleep for 5 seconds *************/        
        Thread background = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // Thread will sleep for 5 seconds
                    // show progress bar here 
                    sleep(5*1000);

                    // After 5 seconds redirect to another intent
                    Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),FirstScreen.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    //Remove activity
                    finish();
                    // hide progress bar here 

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };

        // start thread
        background.start();
```

for more info see below link:-

http://androidexample.com/Splash_screen_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=113&aaid=135

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Comment: I have another doubt , There is no layout folder and when i create it and xml file , and in java code tried to call using R.layout.name then it is showing error , what can i do

Comment: you have to make own layout and put progress bar on splash screen

Comment: I did that man but when i am using the layout in the .java code, by using setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); where i have created layout folder in res folder and inside it has activity_main it is showing error as not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Up until Worklight 6.2 it was not possible to customize the splash screen in a Worklight-based Android application, be it adding a spinner, extending the time the splash is displayed or creating an entirely customized experienced.

Starting Worklight 6.2 the entire flow is customizable if the developer so chooses. This is documented at: [Managing the splash screen in an Android-based hybrid application](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_splash_screen_android.html), which also provides various code examples.

BTW, you already asked about this... [Splash Screen with loading in four environment(android,ios,blackberry and windows) using html coding or common plugin for hybrid apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030875/splash-screen-with-loading-in-four-environmentandroid-ios-blackberry-and-window)