# Splash screen with loading implementation in worklight 6.2

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to implement splash screen with loading in worklight 6.2 . I dont have any reference . Can somebody route me to the correct way.

Comment: Which environment? iOS or Android? What did you implement thus far? **Edit the question** to better illustrate the expected result.

Comment: What does "loading implementation" mean? Search for the  `ShowSplashScreenSpinner` preference for Cordova - it may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to accomplish cannot be done using JavaScript. You will need implement native code in Objective-C and Java.

See [this user documentation topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_splash_screen.html?lang=en) for creating a customized splash screen in iOS and Android.

Based on the documentation, you could add native code to display a busy indicator on top of the splash image. While the app is loading, the Worklight framework will handle the showing and hiding of the splash image.

For example, you could take the following code snippet and insert it in the native code (iOS) per the documentation to add the busy indicator. Google for similar code for Android.

- [How to display an activity indicator with UIViewActivityIndicatorView](http://getsetgames.com/2009/12/03/iphonedev-advent-tip-3-how-to-display-an-activity-indicator-with-uiactivityindicatorview/)

Related question:

- [Splash Screen with loading in four environment(android,ios,blackberry and windows) using html coding or common plugin for hybrid apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030875/splash-screen-with-loading-in-four-environmentandroid-ios-blackberry-and-window/24031326#24031326)

You could also create something else entirely.